# how to prove the following functions are analytic?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to prove that the following functions are analytic using Cauchy-Riemann.

[image]

Is there an easy trick I don't see to prove those are analytic? I'm not asking for a whole calculation, just for a hint, as of now I've been stuck for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Can you differentiate it? If a function $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ has a derivative everywhere in a domain, then it is analytic in that domain. Your first function is analytic everywhere. The second is analytic except where the denominator is $0$.

Any you are mistaken about the theorem you quote as not requiring analytic functions. It requires $f$ to be analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!
for the second function I'll have to try it again because I obtained something that didn't respect Cauchy-Riemann therem. For the first one, I cannot see how to derivate it to have the imaginary part separated from the real part? I need it to prove it is analytic using C-R.

Comment: When I said differentiate it, I meant with respect to $z$, not $x$ and $y$. There is no need to separate it into real or imaginary parts. If you can differentiate with respect to $z$, then it automatically satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. And since I assume you already know that $\frac{d\sin z}{dz} = \cos z$, that polynomials are differentiable, and that the chain rule holds for complex functions just like it does for real ones, this is not hard to do.

Comment: thanks! I didn't think I could to it simply this way!! Was trying to much.